# Changing the text of an element on click in Angular/HTML?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-accordion with mat-expansion-panels. Upon clicking the mat-expansion panels, I would like the text to become underlined. So when the expansion panels are open, the title would be underlined, and when it is closed, the underline disappears. Is there a simple way to alter the text based on the state of the element in Angular/HTML?

Comment: you coud simply use stylesheet :) but to be more accurate you should add more detail regarding your solution, so show your code

Answer (score 1):

The html file could look like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel [(expanded)]="expanded">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header >
        <mat-panel-title [ngClass]="{'underlined': expanded}" >Title</mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

in your typescript file you define the respective field

```
expanded = false;
```

and in the css/scss file you define the respective class:

```
.underlined {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[look at it at StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-underline-title?file=src/app/app.component.html)